# My [assessment] is that this is a terrible tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assessment) tag (19 questions) seems iffy.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does seem to describe the contents, but in an ambiguous and meta-tag way. There are at least five different kinds of "assessments" for which the tag is used:

- Help with completing homework or school projects (sometimes called "assessments" in academic terminology)
- Job interviewing
- Software testing
- Designing online systems for administering tests to humans (also called "assessments" in academic terminology)
- Specific API classes or methods for handling business objects known as "Assessments".

The second is clearly off-topic, and the first and fourth ones seems be meta-tag uses.

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Some of it is, much of it isn't. The broad concept of "assessments" is not on-topic any more than [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows).

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

In theory it could, but not really in practice. For software testing, we already have the [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing) tag.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. There are many different kinds of assessments. See the first answer above.

**Can we burninate this tag? Or at least make it pass an assessment to be allowed to stay?**

Comment: My [assessment] is that this is a terrible tag.

Comment: Also worth noting: it's under 50 questions, so all you have to do is have knowledge of the subject material and consult with a 20k+ user.

Comment: [testing] seems like a bad tag too. theres too many kinds of tests...

Comment: 8 questions left, 5 open. All of the open questions deserve to be closed.

Comment: All questions closed. Closed questions can be del voted by 20k+ rep

Comment: @EJoshuaS how can Robert claim that he has "knowledge of" assessments?

Comment: Why there are only 4 questions now?

Comment: @Braiam They're being steadily deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All questions have been retagged or closed and deleted. Tag is burninated!