# When is the burnination complete banner shown?

Tags: support, burninate-system

I stumbled upon [My [assessment] is that this is a terrible tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369874/7910454) which has a nifty banner informing me that

> This tag has been burninated! If you notice it re-appearing with some frequency, please propose that it be blacklisted.

However, if I check the rest of the [487 completed burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+status-completed), some do not have this banner. I even found [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/7910454) which has a different banner.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The [godaddy] post now has the same banner, at least for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is part of the official process as described in [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

There are instructions in that process for the moderator that handle these requests, like

> - The moderator will add a post notice (Featured Burninate Request), which displays as a large banner at the top of the question.
> - The post notice will be updated to In-progress Burninate Request.
> - Switch the post notice to Completed Burninate Request.

The process only came into existence in 2016 and not all burninations have to follow that process. The moderator responsible will handle adding/updating the post notices.

So only the requests after that date and that were eligible for the process got that notice.

The godaddy burnination <s>has</s> had the wrong notice. A moderator <s>should</s> change*d* it.
Blame [Madara](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/331817/13) for not following our strict process  ;)

Comment: Banner updated.